# How to change the color scheme of Word?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-office, office-interop

How can I change the color scheme of Microsoft Word programmatically using C#?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const string OfficeCommonKey = @"Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common";
            const string OfficeThemeValueName = "Theme";
            const int ThemeBlue = 1;
            const int ThemeSilver = 2;
            const int ThemeBlack = 3;

            using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(OfficeCommonKey, true))
            {

                int theme = (int)key.GetValue(OfficeThemeValueName,1);

                switch (theme)
                {
                    case ThemeBlue:
                        //...

                        break;
                    case ThemeSilver:
                       // ...

                        break;
                    case ThemeBlack:
                       // ...

                        break;
                    default:
                       // ...
                        break;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'r on Word 2010, then following should do it, you need to pass one of theme enums.

```
ActiveDocument.DocumentTheme.ThemeColorScheme(msoThemeLight2)
```

Here you can find [A complete list of Word and Office ThemeColorIndex Enumeration Constants](http://www.wordarticles.com/Articles/Colours/2007.php)

Comment: This is assuming he's using or going to use Office Interop.

Comment: @DaveZych it is tagged as such which makes it assertion ;)

Comment: @LIUFA by using  ActiveDocument.DocumentTheme.ThemeColorScheme.Colors(MsoThemeColorSchemeIndex.msoThemeDark1); colorSheme doesnot change. Where am I doing wrong?